# FQL query to get tagged photos of specific user returning error

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, friend, photos

How to get tagged photos from particular friend? I'm now using this code

> SELECT pid,src,images FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=$uid)

this is the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 1: An unknown error occurred thrown in /FBapps/album-downloader-pro/php-sdk/base_facebook.php on line 1254

This one working for some friends? But not for all. Is this a error of query ?

Answer (score 0):

The FQL query you've given would only return photos if the user has permission to view them. Also, the user would need approve the 'user_photos' permission for you to access their photos.

What is the actual error message you are getting from Facebook, rather than the PHP error?